# heroku precompile error for javascript using for..of loop

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm working on a Rails app. Everything was working fine in development. Then, I went to deploy my rails app on heroku. But the heroku build failed when pre-compiling assets. It reported the following error.

```
rake aborted!
remote:        ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token name «of», expected punc «;» (line: 15234, col: 16, pos: 937232)
remote:        Error
```

It seems that there is problematic "of" somewhere in my code.

I began searching and found a use of "of" in a javascripit file that could be the problem.

I have this piece of code in one of my javascript files which uses a for..of loop

```
$.get("/paragraphimage/showzoom/" + itemid + "/" + msslug + "/" + pid, function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var i = 1;
            for(var zone of data){
                id = Math.random()
                if (i == 1){
                    $("#lbp-para-picture-window").append("<div id='openseadragon-" + id + "' style='width: " + zone.width + "px; height: " + zone.height + "px; margin: auto; padding-bottom: 5px;'></div>")
                }
                else{
                    $("#lbp-para-picture-window").append("<div id='openseadragon-" + id + "' style='width: " + zone.width + "px; height: " + zone.height + "px; margin: auto; padding-bottom: 5px;'></div>") 
                }
                showOpenseadragon(id, zone);
                i = i + 1
            };
        });
```

*just to clarify. `data` is an array of json objects and I'm attempting to iterate over each json object in the array.

'data' looks like this:

```
   [
  {
    "scale": 0.9508716323296355,
    "bottom": 1727.7337559429477,
    "right": 768.3042789223455,
    "top": 1586.053882725832,
    "left": 168.30427892234547,
    "width": 600,
    "height": 141.67987321711567,
    "totalW": 1622.187004754358,
    "totalH": 2146.117274167987,
    "aspectratio": 1.3229777256740913,
    "xcomp": 0.10375146541617819,
    "ycomp": 0.9777256740914418,
    "heightcomp": 0.0873388042203986,
    "widthcomp": 0.3698710433763189,
    "image_url": {
      "scheme": "http",
      "authority": "images.scta.info:3000",
      "userinfo": null,
      "user": null,
      "password": null,
      "host": "images.scta.info",
      "port": 3000,
      "path": "/pp-reims/R1r.jpg",
      "query": null,
      "fragment": null
    }
  },
  {
    "scale": 0.9508716323296355,
    "bottom": 1038.351822503962,
    "right": 1347.3851030110934,
    "top": 167.35340729001584,
    "left": 747.3851030110935,
    "width": 600,
    "height": 870.998415213946,
    "totalW": 1622.187004754358,
    "totalH": 2146.117274167987,
    "aspectratio": 1.3229777256740913,
    "xcomp": 0.46072684642438455,
    "ycomp": 0.10316529894490033,
    "heightcomp": 0.536928487690504,
    "widthcomp": 0.3698710433763189,
    "image_url": {
      "scheme": "http",
      "authority": "images.scta.info:3000",
      "userinfo": null,
      "user": null,
      "password": null,
      "host": "images.scta.info",
      "port": 3000,
      "path": "/pp-reims/R1r.jpg",
      "query": null,
      "fragment": null
    }
  }
]
```

RubyMine also does not like this for...of loop and highlights it as an error.

I began looking this up at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility

for...of seems like acceptable code but experimental

I thought that I could change this to for...in. But for...in does something slightly different and also appears to be depreciated. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in)

So, questions:

Is it likely that this `for...of` is the the reason for the pre-compile error on Heroku?

If so, why does my local machine support it while Heroku does not support it.

Finally, how should I change the above javascript code so that Heroku can successfully precompile the assets?

Answer (score 0):

As an ECMAScript 6 feature, it may not be fully supported because ES6 hasn't been finalized. If you used a more traditional for loop you could combine the code used to increment your loop with the context.

```
for(i = 0;i<data.length;i++) {
  if (i == 0) {
    $("#lbp-para-picture-window").append("<div id='openseadragon-" + id + "' style='width: " + data[i].width + "px; height: " + data[i].height + "px; margin: auto; padding-bottom: 5px;'></div>")
  } else {
    $("#lbp-para-picture-window").append("<div id='openseadragon-" + id + "' style='width: " + data[i].width + "px; height: " + data[i].height + "px; margin: auto; padding-bottom: 5px;'></div>") 
  }
  showOpenseadragon(id, data[i]);
}
```

Notice that it starts on 0 here instead of 1. And unless I'm missing something, your code in the `else` condition is the same as the `if` condition. So you could refactor that if it isn't necessary.